# Integral of Associated Legendre Functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

Does anyone know how to compute the following integrals:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{P_l^m(x) P_n^m(x)}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx
$$
and
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} P_l^m(x) P_n^m(x) dx
$$
where $P_l^m$ is an associated Legendre polynomial? Here, $l,n,m$ are integers.

Comment: You will find a lot of useful information here: https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~westra/associatedlegendrefunctions.pdf

Comment: check: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3596140/614585

Comment: How about this one: [please add more detail like context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Settle down Tyma. The question is well posed and stands on its own